# Reading from multiple ADC channels on ATMEGA128

Tags: avr, adc

I am trying to read the value from two analogue infrared sensors on an ATMega128 dev board and then output a scaled representation via PWM. When I connect the two PWM waves to the oscilloscope they remain identical which shouldn't be the case. My PWM code is fine so I think the problem lies in my code for reading from channel 0 and 1 of the ADC.

```
int sens1,sens2,sens3;
volatile const uint8_t adc1 = (1<<ADLAR) | (0<<MUX0)|(0<<MUX1);
volatile const uint8_t adc2 = (1<<ADLAR) | (1<<MUX0)|(0<<MUX1);

void main(void)
{


ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0); 
ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0); // Set ADC reference to AVCC
ADMUX |= (1 << ADLAR); // Left adjust ADC result to allow easy 8 bit reading
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADFR);  // Set ADC to Free-Running Mode
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN);  // Enable ADC
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIE);  // Enable ADC Interrupt
sei();  // Enable Global Interrupts
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);  // Start A2D Conversions

while (1)
{
}
}

ISR(ADC_vect)
{

static uint8_t firstTime = 1;
static uint8_t val;

val = ADCH*100;

if (firstTime == 1){
firstTime = 0;
}
else if (ADMUX == adc1)
{
    ADMUX = adc2;
    OCR3A = val;
}

else if (ADMUX == adc2)
{
    ADMUX = adc1;
    OCR1C = val;
}
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine from a quick look. I would verify that each ADC channel gives expected results without switching between channels to narrow it down.

Comment: Each channel gives expected results

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `firstTime` to 1 after input channel change.
please refer data sheet for this:

> When changing channel selections, the user should observe the
>   following guidelines to ensure that the correct channel is selected:
>
> [...]
>   In Free Running mode, always select the channel before
>   starting the first conversion. The channel selection may be changed
>   one ADC clock cycle after writing one to ADSC. However, the simplest
>   method is to wait for the first conversion to complete, and then
>   change the channel selection. Since the next conversion has already
>   started automatically, the next result will reflect the previous
>   channel selection. Subsequent conversions will reflect the new channel
>   selection.

But why using Free Running Mode at all? You want an interrupt. So you may select source and trigger measurement and wait for interrupt. Then manually start the next measurement.

The other thing that alerts me is the multiplication of the `uint8_t` result with 100.
Are you sure that this will not overflow?
what is the input voltage range of our ADC-Channels?

Another Reason may be the sampling frequency. You chose a very high prescaler. The ADC requires at least 50kHz clock. So your AVR should run at > 6Mhz. Check if your Fuse settings are set to use the external clock source. And one more thing. Documentation of Fuse Bits say that AtMega103 compatibility mode seems to be active by default. You may refer the datesheet maybe this also effects your problem.